# How to put links into description text?

Tags: forms, navigation, i18n-l10n, theming

In my field's description, I want to link to more documentation. If I do it like this:

```
$form['field_name'] = array (
  '#description' => t('Here are some words about') . ' <a href="http://mysite.com/blah">' . t('stuff') . '</a> ' . t('and things and whatnot'),
);
```

It works. It looks like this:

> Here are some words about [stuff](http://mysite.com/blah) and things and
>   whatnot.

If I do it the proper way, like this:

```
$form['field_name'] = array (
  '#description' => t('Here are some words about @stuff and things and whatnot', array('@stuff' => l('stuff', 'blah')),
);
```

Then the HTML is generated and then output into my description as raw text, like so:

> Here are some words about <a href="http://mysite.com/blah">stuff</a> and things and
>   whatnot.

Why is the "correct" way not working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, here are some of the ways ***NOT*** to pass links to the `t()` function:

```
// DO NOT DO THESE THINGS
$BAD_EXTERNAL_LINK = t('Look at Drupal documentation at !handbook.', array('!handbook' => '<a href="http://drupal.org/handbooks">'. t('the Drupal Handbooks') .'</a>'));

$ANOTHER_BAD_EXTERNAL_LINK = t('Look at Drupal documentation at <a href="http://drupal.org/handbooks">the Drupal Handbooks</a>.');

$BAD_INTERNAL_LINK = t('To get an overview of your administration options, go to !administer in the main menu.', array('!administer' => l(t('the Administer screen'), 'admin'));
```

And these are the accepted ways *to* pass that type of arg:

```
// Do this instead.
$external_link = t('Look at Drupal documentation at <a href="@drupal-handbook">the Drupal Handbooks</a>.', array('@drupal-handbook' => 'http://drupal.org/handbooks'));

$internal_link = t('To get an overview of your administration options, go to <a href="@administer-page">the Administer screen</a> in the main menu.', array('@administer-page' => url('admin')));
```

This all comes from [Dynamic or static links and HTML in translatable strings](https://drupal.org/node/322774), which contains justifications for that reasoning.

Comment: The first one is what I did already.

Comment: @beth Do you mean the one called `$BAD_EXTERNAL_LINK`? That (and the other two in that block) are what ***not*** to do. The second code block contains the correct code to use. Neither of those are the same as what you tried

Comment: Whoops, yes you're right.